# Console Window shown despite using OutputType WinExe with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

If i add `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` to a new ConsoleApp the app gets started, the Main method is run and the app is shut down again.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If i change the Sdk to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and start the app again, a console window is opened.

Why does using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` cause a console window to open? Is there a way to prevent that?

Edit: It seems like the console window is only opened if the app is started in Visual Studio. If i run the exe without Visual Studio the app is run as a background process, as expected.

Edit2: I will try to rephrase the question:

Using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` causes a bunch of props and target files to be included into the project. Somewhere in there must be the reason for the console window to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on GitHub and got confirmation that this is a bug in visual studio.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6613

Answer (score 0):

**Why does using  cause a console window to open? Is there a way to prevent that?**

When you change your project to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` which means it is a web project, you did not reload your project correctly. It missed a `launchSettings.json` file which will specify to start your project as a website.

**In my side**, if you did not reload your project correctly, it will miss `launchSettings.json` file, so when you run your project, it will start a console window:

[image]

**Suggestion**

**1)** Close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**2)**,restart VS to open your project to reinitialize the project.

It will generate `launchSettings.json` file.

[image]

This is my test result and **it will not call a console window**.

[image]

**Besides**, if your project already has a `launchSettings.json` file, you could delete it and then follow **step 1** and **step 2** to recreate the file.

Comment: You don't get the Console Window because you are running the app in IISExpress. That is definitely not what i want. Also, i do get the LaunchSettings.json, i also tried to modify and delete it but there seems to be no way to not have VS open a console window.
So again, the question would be: Why does the Web Sdk cause a console window to pop up in Visual Studio? There should at least be a Property to turn that off, no?

Comment: How did you run your app without iis?  Could you please share some steps with us? `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` means that it is an asp net web project and you should use iis. Otherwise, if you   change the launch format, it will use the changed way. Or please share us more detailed info.

Comment: You don't need to use iis to run an asp app. You can use e.g. Kestrel. But that's not the point. Just use "ConsoleAppX" instead of "IIS Express" and you will see the console window pop up. But it should not do this since we have OutputType WinExe specified.

Comment: Also using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` does not mean that this is an "asp net web project". It means that a bunch of props and target files will be included. Wether or not i'm adding something web related to the project is up to me. So maybe i should rephrase my question: What part in all those props and target files causes the console window and how can i get rid of it? Or maybe it's just Visual Studio that is doing things i have not asked for.